# Compiling adding extra code in C to NASM, causing errors

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm

The closet I have gotten to actually reasonable code is removing `-m16` from `gcc`, but I get 64 bit intruction errors

I am trying to build `C` to `.asm` via `gcc` and `objconv`, but it outputs unnecessary code, that causes issues with other compiled code.

I also get an error while importing main.c:

`main.asm:20: error: binary output format does not support external references`

(Original nasm file extension: `.s` | `C` converted to nasm: `.asm`):

Expected output:

```
setc:
    call    draw_first_scene
    call    init_mouse
    jmp     enable_mouse
```

Output:

```
extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
setc:
    push    bx
?_001:
    db 66H, 0E8H
    dd __x86.get_pc_thunk.bx-$-6H
    db 66H, 81H, 0C3H
    dd _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_-$-6H
    dd 08EC8366H
    db 66H, 0E8H
    dd draw_first_scene-$-17H
    db 66H, 0E8H
    dd init_mouse-$-1DH
    db 66H, 0E8H
    dd enable_mouse-$-23H
    dd 08C48366H, 0C3665B66H
__x86.get_pc_thunk.bx:
    mov     bx, word [si]
    and     al, 66H
    ret
```

Removed `-m16` output:

```
extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
setc:
    sub     rsp, 8
    xor     eax, eax
    call    draw_first_scene
    xor     eax, eax
    call    init_mouse
    xor     eax, eax
    add     rsp, 8
    jmp     enable_mouse
```

main.c:

```c
void setc() {
    draw_first_scene();
    init_mouse();
    enable_mouse();
}
```

boot.s:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

; NASM
%include "bpb.s"
%include "mouse.s"
%include "draw.s"
%include "scene_draw.s"
%include "mouse_draw.s"

; C
%include "main.asm"

boot_start:
    xor ax,ax
    mov ds,ax
    mov ss,ax
    mov sp,0x7c00
    cld
    mov ax,12h
    int 10h
    jmp 0x0:setc
    sti
.main_loop:
    hlt
    call draw_mouse
    jmp .main_loop

.no_mouse:
    mov si,noMouseMsg
    call print_string

.err_loop:
    hlt
    jmp .err_loop
```

bpb.s:

```
bits 16
org 0x7c00

global bpb_disk_info

mov ax,07c0h
add ax,544
cli
mov ss,ax
mov sp,4096
sti
    
jmp boot_start
nop

bpb_disk_info:
    OEMLabel: db "mkfs.fat"
    BytesPerSector: dw 512
    SectorsPerCluster: db 1
    ReservedForBoot: dw 1
    NumberOfFats: db 2
    RootDirEntries: dw 224

    LogicalSectors: dw 2880
    MediumByte: db 0f0h
    SectorsPerFat: dw 9
    SectorsPerTrack: dw 18
    Sides: dw 2
    HiddenSectors: dd 0
    LargeSectors: dd 0
    DriveNo: dw 0
    Signature: db 41
    VolumeID: dd 0x2d7e5a1a
    VolumeLabel: db "           "
    FileSystem: db "FAT12   "
```

My build.sh (I am running Linux on [repl.it](https://replit.com/@8O4k/Reliq#main.sh) as I am on chromebook):

```sh
clear
set echo off

cleanup() {
    {
        rm -r $cur/node_modules/out
        rm -r $cur/node_modules/temp
        export temp=$prevtemp
        export cur=$prevcur
    } &>/dev/null
    exit
}
trap cleanup 0

{
    export prevtemp=$temp
    export pervcur=$cur
    export temp=""
    export temp2=""
    export cur="$(cd -- "$(dirname "$0")" >/dev/null 2>&1 ; pwd -P)"
    export cur=${cur%/node_modules}
    cd $cur
    mkdir nasm
    mkdir node_modules
    cd node_modules
    mkdir out
    mkdir temp
    export temp=${cur}/node_modules/temp
    cd $cur/src
} &> /dev/null

for i in $(find . -type f -print); do
    if [[ "$i" == *.c ]]; then
        export temp=${i/%.c/.o}
        gcc -m16 -Wno-implicit-function-declaration -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables -s -c -o $cur/node_modules/out${temp#.} $cur/src${i#.}
    else
        cp -f $i $cur/node_modules/out
    fi
done

cd $cur/node_modules/out

for i in $(find . -type f -print); do
    if [[ "$i" == *.o ]]; then
        export temp=${i/%.o/.asm}
        {
            objconv -fnasm $cur/node_modules/out${i#.}
            mv $cur/node_modules/out${temp#.} $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            
            sed -i -e "/^SECTION ./d" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "s/\s*;/;/g" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "/^;/d" -e "s/^\([^;]*\);.*$/\1/" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "/^global/d" -e "s/^\([^global]*\)global.*$/\1/" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "/^default/d" -e "s/^\([^default]*\)default.*$/\1/" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "/^extern/d" -e "s/^\([^extern]*\)extern.*$/\1/" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -r "/^\s*$/d" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i -e "s/        /  /g" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
            sed -i "1s/^/extern _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_\n/" $cur/nasm${temp#.}
        } &> /dev/null
    fi
done
{
    cd $cur/node_modules
} &> /dev/null

cd $cur/nasm

nasm -O0 -w+other -w+orphan-labels -f bin -o $cur/node_modules/out/boot.bin $cur/nasm/boot.s

cd $cur/node_modules/out

for i in $(find . -type f -print); do
    if [[ "$i" == *.o ]]; then
        rm $cur/node_modules/out${i#.}
    fi
done

{
    mkdosfs -C reliq.flp 1440
    dd status=noxfer conv=notrunc if=boot.bin of=reliq.flp
    rm reliq.iso
    mkisofs -quiet -V 'RELIQ' -input-charset iso8859-1 -o reliq.iso -b reliq.flp ./
    sleep 0.2
    mv reliq.iso $cur
    cd $cur
} &> /dev/null

{
qemu-system-x86_64 \
-netdev user,id=mynet0 \
-device ne2k_isa,netdev=mynet0 \
-drive file=reliq.iso,media=cdrom,cache=none \
-device sb16 \
-m 512M \
-cpu Cascadelake-Server \
-smp 1 \
-vga vmware \
-display gtk,grab-on-hover=on,zoom-to-fit=off \
-accel tcg \
-boot menu=on
} &> /dev/null
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and create a [mre]. Instead of showing a fairly complex build script, show the complete source code, the exact commands that get executed to build it, the actual and expected output. What "*issues with other compiled code*" exactly do you get? What exactly do you mean with "*importing* main.c"? Show the code the error message refers to and the commands you used to generate it. (assuming `main.asm` was created from `main.c`)

Comment: In `boot.s` you should move those includes to below the rest of the bootsector code. Have *boot_start* directly under `org 0x7C00`. That's where execution starts.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. I suppose "b**d**b.s" is just a typo for "b**p**b.s" ?

Comment: Does all that bootsector code fit in 512 bytes? Also I don't see any signature 0xAA55 in the word at offset 510.

Comment: The *bpb_disk_info* mandatory must be at offset 3 in the bootsector. Remove the redundant setup of a stackpointer (happens twice!) and remove the `nop` because with all of those includes the `jmp boot_start` will already occupy 3 bytes.

Comment: If you don't want GCC to make a mess when creating 16 or 32-bit code, use `-fno-pie`; your distro defaults to making position-independent code.  (Which is cheap on x86-64 where RIP-relative addressing is available, but not for other modes)  You may also want `-fno-stack-protector`

Comment: Also, the normal convention is `.S` for GAS source files, `.asm` for NASM source files.  (Although that's not a strict rule, but I personally find it weird to see a `.s` with NASM directives and syntax.)